# <form:form/> for custom JSTL tag from outer <form:form/>

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a problem while using

```
<form:form/>
```

at mine custom tag when it is placed at main form. Here is example

```
<form:form method="POST" id="form1_id" action="${url1}" modelAttribute="form1">

<div>
...
</div>

<comp:myComp link="${url2}"/>

<div>
....
</div>

<form:form>
```

And this is my tag at myComp.tag file

```
<div>
...
<div>

<jsp:doBody />

<form:form method="POST" id="form2_id" action="${link2}" modelAttribute="uploadForm">
...
<form:button id="myButton"> </form:button>
...
</form:form>
```

The problem is when I push on **myButton** there is no any affect! When I looked on HTML I noticed **there is no  tag** for my **form2_id** form! That's mean when we use nested forms it is not valid. I agree. This is correct. But look carefully at mine example - I've intentionally used

```
<jsp:doBody />
```

tag for placing second form out of the my main form! So what is wrong here?

Comment: "I've intentionally used `jsp:doBody` tag for placing second form out of the main form."... one word - **what**?

Comment: I have two forms. Right? The correct solution here is to place one form after another. That is exactly what I'm trying to do. Whe I use    jsp:doBody I enforce to place the nested form out of the main form. But this approach fails. OK? So my question is **why**?

Comment: `<jsp:doBody>` renders content of the tag (content between the start tag and end tag of the tag itself). It does not affect order of tags in the parent page. Output of your `<jsp:doBody>` will be empty string because your tag does not have any content (`<comp:myComp link="${url2}"/>`).

Comment: If you'd write `<comp:myComp link="${url2}">FOO</comp:myComp>` then the output of `<jsp:doBody />` would be `FOO`. You have misunderstood this JSP directive.

Comment: wow! Thanks Pavel! You opened my eyes! So is there any approach to place part of my tag outside of the form on the main page?

Comment: Do you really need both forms to perform data binding and validation? If not, simply make one of them plain HTML form (i.e. don't use Spring tags). Then you won't have any issues with FORM nesting.

Comment: I am afraid this is not appropriate for me since I need Spring data binding for both forms.

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question and better explain your use case - why you need two distinct forms on one page, why they lead to different URLs and why are they nested in JSP...